# Storing Files locally on Mobile Device using a Webapp

Tags: android, ios, html, web-applications, storage

I need to create an application that does the following:

- Is available for Android and iOS devices primarily, Windows phone support would be nice
- Allows the user to use the app offline
- Allows the user to download files (PNGs and HTMLs) from a webserver to be displayed later within the webapp (needs to be able to be viewed offline)
- Doesn't require user to redownload all the PNGs and HTMLs if they clear their browser cache (would be nice if there was a way to keep them from clearing the web app cache too, but I understand if this is not possible)

What tools do I use for this?  So far, I'm at HTML5 web app and I understand how to cache the site, but how do I get the files (PNGs and HTMLs) to be saved locally and not subject to being cleared should the user clear the browser cache?  Is native for iOS, Android, and Windows the only way to go here?

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to work on multiple platforms and be available offline, your best bet would be to wrap your app in something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) and package it up for the various platforms.

This allows for one common "HTML-based web app" code base but will require compiling for the different platforms respectively.

Comment: I'm worried about the phonegap method performing poorly.  There will be quite a few animations and image loads.  Are you saying that I can't use a client side database that works on android and ios?

Comment: I may be confused in what you are asking. How are you planning on deploying the app? Is it just going to be a responsive website? With regards to offline capabilities, I'm on the iOS side of things so I don't know about Android, but if you don't have web access, mobile Safari tells you "Safari cannot open the page because your iPhone is not connected to the Internet". The only option I am aware of it to create it as a native application hence wrapping an HTML-based app in something like PhoneGap or Titanium Appcelerator.

Comment: I've dabbled a bit in phonegap, but I noticed that the animations were pretty slow on my android device when I ran some test apps with similar functionality.  I'd like the app to be as similar as possible on android and ios devices, but the user needs to be able to download about 20-30mb worth of images and pngs that can be viewed offline.  The problem i'm seeing with a webapp (HTML5) is if the user clears safaris cache, the next time they connect, they will have to download all 20-30mb worth of files again.

Comment: deployment doesn't matter.  Can be deployed through play/app store or via a website.  that part is not a factor

Comment: i'm more interested in using internal storage on android/ios device

Comment: the crappy part is I've already created it natively for android,... but now i need to port to ios and I'm trying to figure out if native for ios is now my best bet, given that i'd have to deal with maintaining 2 code bases, or if i should switch delivery platform altogether.

Comment: Ah... So the dilemma is whether to go native or find some other multi-platform solution and move your app into that. We've got an app that we built originally as native just for iOS (universal for iPhone and iPad) and as opposed to going the HTML-wrapped app route, built it for Android natively too. It was not fun, but since this app is going to be around for a while, for us the two code bases are worth the investment to gain the advantage of native capabilities for animations/video/images of both device groups.

Comment: Yes.  That's the dilemna.  I'm really not excited about learning iOS development, but I will if I have to.  If I could access internal storage using a webapp, I think i'd be set to move it all to a webapp